# How to clear text from the Radeditor in telerik

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have a Radeditor, a telerik control which has similar functionality as word. The application currently supports cut option, which cuts the plain text, but that feature on the editor doesn't work for large chunks of data and also doesn't delete data across multiple cells in a table. For the above 2 cases it gives a warning saying: Use Ctrl+X instead and cut the content. 
The Client wants to select the content and cut it from the telerik editor.

I have researched a lot online, but had no luck yet. Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: The content cut problem is a browser behavior. Here is what is available in RadEditor's documentation: The Cut , Copy and Paste tools use the native browser’s client-side commands to trigger the corresponding clipboard operation. Some browsers restrict such clipboard manipulations due to security matters, and thus the tools to not apply any changes. In such cases, the RadEditor prompts the end-user to use the keyboard shortcut combination to cut, copy or paste content.
http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/editor/managing-content/pasting-content/overview

Comment: Thanks that makes sense.